# unable to see output as expected when using forEach logic in js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

My requirement is to display the bar graph.I'm using angularjs and Zingchart to display the bar. Belowis the javascript code which gets invoked to generate the bar. I'm facing issue in iterating the logic(angular.forEach..) in the below mentioned code.

My alert statement inside angular.forEach is displayed 3 times, but on the UI i can only see one bar displayed(i.e.,bar with final data is displayed, first two bars are not getting displayed).
I know i'm missing something which draws each and every bar instead of the last displayed bar. Do i need to use any push statemetns. Please advice.

```
app.controller('myController',['$rootScope','$scope','$uibModal','myService',function($rootScope,$scope,$uibModal,myService)  {
    $scope.chart = {};
    $scope.chart.options = {
        "isStacked": "true",
         axisFontSize : 10,
        chartArea: {left:0, width: 400,}
    };
    $scope.chart.type = "bar";
    $scope.chart.cssStyle = "height:300px; width:650px;";

    $scope.loadChartData = function(){
        alert("Chart data loading");
        MyService.getChartData($rootScope.myID).then(
            function(response) {
                $scope.myJson=response;
                  angular.forEach($scope.myJson,function(value,key){
                      alert("in foreach"); //displaying 3 times
                      sub =  value.myResults.sub;
                      spread = value.myResults.spread;
                      active  =value.myResults.active;
                    $scope.data = {};
                    $scope.data.valuesOne = [sub];
                    $scope.data.valuesTwo = [spread];
                    $scope.data.valuesThree = [active];
                    $scope.aValues = [$scope.data.valuesOne,$scope.data.valuesTwo,$scope.data.valuesThree];
                    $scope.myJson = {
                        type : "bar",
                        "background-color": "white",
                        "plot": {
                            "stacked": true,
                            "stack-type":"normal"
                        },
                        title:{
                            backgroundColor : "transparent",
                            fontColor :"black",
                            text : "Hello world"
                        },
                        backgroundColor : "white",
                        series : [
                            {
                                backgroundColor : '#00baf2'
                            },
                            {
                                backgroundColor : '#4caf4f'
                            }
                        ]
                    };
             });
            },
            function(errResponse){
                console.error('Error while data retrieval');
            });
    }

}]);
```

html code:

```
  <div ng-controller="myController">
            <div zingchart id="chart-2" zc-json="myJson" zc-width="700px" zc-height="568px" zc-values="aValues"></div>
  </div>
```

With the above mentioned js code i should see 3 bars on the UI, i could able to view only one bar.Please suggest.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML Source?

Comment: I am also just wondering where myResults are coming from.

Comment: @RemoL. - myResults are coming back from my service call MyService.getChartData(..) .I check the results, everything is fine, only issue is while looping something i'm missing to draw the graph which is the reason its only drawing last data bar on the UI instead of showing 3 bars.Please see my edited code above, included the html code.

Comment: @dan - Can you help how to proceed to push each of myJson value. Thanks.

Comment: @DIM, did you already solve it? Otherwise, can you post the value of `response`, which you store in `$scope.myJson`?

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg , the below answer by dan works, but only difference is i want to display the bars differently.i.e.,value.myResults.sub, value.myResults.spread, value.myResults.active should show one stacked bar.  But with below code first stacked bar is created using values from value.myResults.sub, second stacked bar is created using values from value.myResults.spread..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call foreach on the data, rather than the whole chart. Like this:

```
...
function(response) {

    $scope.myJson = {
        type: "bar",
        "background-color": "white",
        "plot": {
            "stacked": true,
            "stack-type": "normal"
        },
        title: {
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            fontColor: "black",
            text: "Hello world"
        },
        backgroundColor: "white",
        series: [
            {
                backgroundColor: '#00baf2'
            },
            {
                backgroundColor: '#4caf4f'
            }
        ]
    };

    var subs = []
    var spreads = []
    var actives = []

    $scope.aValues = [subs, spreads, actives]

    angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) {
        subs.push(value.myResults.sub)
        spreads.push(value.myResults.spreads)
        actives.push(value.myResults.active)
    });
},
function(errResponse) {
    console.error('Error while data retrieval');
});
...
```

Comment: @DIM hmmm, can you confirm `$scope.charts` is outside `angular.forEach(...)`. If so, what happens if you console.log($scope.charts) after `$scope.charts.push(chart)`? It should log 3 times, each time with an extra chart.

Comment: thanks for the support, but the output is same as before. I can only see one bar instead of 3 bars on UI. Any suggestions would be helpful.thanks.

Comment: @DIM also, can you try changing `id="chart-2"` to `id="chart-{{$index}}"`

Comment: I can see 3 different bars graphs separately on the UI , and each one however displaying only one bar information instead of 3bars. Console.log statement is as follows: After push :[object Object]
chartController.js:78 After push :[object Object],[object Object]
chartController.js:78 After push :[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Please see my original post, i have included the image. I'm only getting one bar but 3 times..

Comment: @DIM Sorry, I completely misunderstood what you were trying to do there. Ok, your problem should be simpler to solve. Are `sub`, `spread` and `active` the three bars you're wanting to plot on a single chart?

Comment: no..i think you understood correct..sub,spread,active are 3 different values should be displayed one after the other as stacked bar which is happening now. and you can see that in the image with 3 different colors each one representing. Currently i have 3 ID's data which i'm getting from database. so i need to show 3 bars which should be dynamic. If i have 10 Id's with data i will get 10 bars.Currently i have 3 ID's data so i should get 3 bars displayed.

Comment: `ng-repeat` will only repeat the chart tag. You need to pass several series to the directive.

Comment: @dan - As per our discussion yesterday, i tried to modify the array elements which are used to display the stacked bar but with no luck. I treid as         $scope.aValues.push([value.myResults.sub], [value.myResults.spread], [value.myResults.active]); so that while displaying the stacked bar it picks elements from sub,spread and active and display the bar.But i end up with only one single bar and all records are stacked one on other even for other Id's also.Thanks.

Comment: @dan - With the above code i see three stacked bars one taking first element values for sub, second stacked bar taking values of spread and third one for active.Actually i want my [sub,spread,active] represent stacked bar and depending on how many records i will get from database that many stacked bars it will create. To make it simple in the example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmQPaz , [4628, 390,76] should represent first stacked bar,[3428,98,26] should represent second stacked bar and [2118,40,16] should represent third stacked bar.

Comment: @DIM we got there in the end! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things I have to add:

### 1. Zingchart Syntax

Did you already have a look at these docs: https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/bar-charts/

It says, the **bar chart** needs a **series** object as input with the following structure:

```
  "series": [
    {"values":[20,40,25,50,15,45,33,34]},
    {"values":[5,30,21,18,59,50,28,33]},
    {"values":[30,5,18,21,33,41,29,15]}
   ]
```

Is it a must to feed the chart from HTML? Otherwise you just could copy the JS example from the link above.
IMHO this is much cleaner, as you do not push that much data in the scope.

### 2. Overwriting myJson

Something looks a little wrong with the `forEach` loop.

There is a `angular.forEach` that should iterate over the array `$scope.myJson`. But inside the iterator function, `$scope.myJson` gets overwrtitten by an object.

### 3. ng-repeat

`ng-repeat` will only repeat the chart tag. You need to pass several series to the directive.